# My header and cpp files were deleted from the folder and i dont know how to restore it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

I just tried to open my project in the VS 2017 and suddenly i cant see one of my classes files.
The header and the cpp are missing.
The files are not in the folder and i cant even see them in the Cmake.
When i start the VS and trying to open the project it says:

ex01_files (the name of the folder) could not be opened. Do you want to remove the reference(s) to it from the Recent list(s)?

when i open the project, i get an error at the top that says:

C++ IntelliSense information may be out of date, generate the CMake cache to refresh.

Im new at the VS so im afraid to take action by myself.

Comment: Can you see the files outside of Visual Studio? If you just look using Windows Explorer? That's the important question and the thing you need to check. Can't really make any suggestions without knowing the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just removed the `header and cpp` in VS, you could find these files in the corresponding folder.
2. If you deleted these files, you could try to find them in the Recycle Bin.
3. If you deleted these files completely, I suggested that you could use [Windows File Recovery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recover-lost-files-on-windows-10-61f5b28a-f5b8-3cc2-0f8e-a63cb4e1d4c4) to recover lost files.